# Ensemble of different kinds of regressors using scikit-learn (or any other python framework)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I am trying to solve the regression task. I found out that 3 models are working nicely for different subsets of data: LassoLARS, SVR and Gradient Tree Boosting. I noticed that when I make predictions using all these 3 models and then make a table of 'true output' and outputs of my 3 models I see that each time at least one of the models is really close to the true output, though 2 others could be relatively far away.

When I compute minimal possible error (if I take prediction from 'best' predictor for each test example) I get a error which is much smaller than error of any model alone. So I thought about trying to combine predictions from these 3 diffent models into some kind of ensemble. Question is, how to do this properly? All my 3 models are build and tuned using scikit-learn, does it provide some kind of a method which could be used to pack models into ensemble? The problem here is that I don't want to just average predictions from all three models, I want to do this with weighting, where weighting should be determined based on properties of specific example.

Even if scikit-learn not provides such functionality, it would be nice if someone knows how to property address this task - of figuring out the weighting of each model for each example in data. I think that it might be done by a separate regressor built on top of all these 3 models, which will try output optimal weights for each of 3 models, but I am not sure if this is the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a known interesting (and often painful!) problem with hierarchical predictions. A problem with training a number of predictors over the train data, then training a higher predictor over them, again using the train data - has to do with the bias-variance decomposition.

Suppose you have two predictors, one essentially an overfitting version of the other, then the former will appear over the train set to be better than latter. The combining predictor will favor the former for no true reason, just because it cannot distinguish overfitting from true high-quality prediction.

The known way of dealing with this is to prepare, for each row in the train data, for each of the predictors, a prediction for the row, based on a model *not* fit for this row. For the overfitting version, e.g., this won't produce a good result for the row, on average. The combining predictor will then be able to better assess a fair model for combining the lower-level predictors.

Shahar Azulay & I wrote a transformer stage for dealing with this:

```
class Stacker(object):
    """
    A transformer applying fitting a predictor `pred` to data in a way
        that will allow a higher-up predictor to build a model utilizing both this 
        and other predictors correctly.

    The fit_transform(self, x, y) of this class will create a column matrix, whose 
        each row contains the prediction of `pred` fitted on other rows than this one. 
        This allows a higher-level predictor to correctly fit a model on this, and other
        column matrices obtained from other lower-level predictors.

    The fit(self, x, y) and transform(self, x_) methods, will fit `pred` on all 
        of `x`, and transform the output of `x_` (which is either `x` or not) using the fitted 
        `pred`.

    Arguments:    
        pred: A lower-level predictor to stack.

        cv_fn: Function taking `x`, and returning a cross-validation object. In `fit_transform`
            th train and test indices of the object will be iterated over. For each iteration, `pred` will
            be fitted to the `x` and `y` with rows corresponding to the
            train indices, and the test indices of the output will be obtained
            by predicting on the corresponding indices of `x`.
    """
    def __init__(self, pred, cv_fn=lambda x: sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut(x.shape[0])):
        self._pred, self._cv_fn  = pred, cv_fn

    def fit_transform(self, x, y):
        x_trans = self._train_transform(x, y)

        self.fit(x, y)

        return x_trans

    def fit(self, x, y):
        """
        Same signature as any sklearn transformer.
        """
        self._pred.fit(x, y)

        return self

    def transform(self, x):
        """
        Same signature as any sklearn transformer.
        """
        return self._test_transform(x)

    def _train_transform(self, x, y):
        x_trans = np.nan * np.ones((x.shape[0], 1))

        all_te = set()
        for tr, te in self._cv_fn(x):
            all_te = all_te | set(te)
            x_trans[te, 0] = self._pred.fit(x[tr, :], y[tr]).predict(x[te, :]) 
        if all_te != set(range(x.shape[0])):
            warnings.warn('Not all indices covered by Stacker', sklearn.exceptions.FitFailedWarning)

        return x_trans

    def _test_transform(self, x):
        return self._pred.predict(x)
```

---

Here is an example of the improvement for the setting described in @MaximHaytovich's answer.

First, some setup:

```
    from sklearn import linear_model
    from sklearn import cross_validation
    from sklearn import ensemble
    from sklearn import metrics

    y = np.random.randn(100)
    x0 = (y + 0.1 * np.random.randn(100)).reshape((100, 1)) 
    x1 = (y + 0.1 * np.random.randn(100)).reshape((100, 1)) 
    x = np.zeros((100, 2))
```

Note that `x0` and `x1` are just noisy versions of `y`. We'll use the first 80 rows for train, and the last 20 for test.

These are the two predictors: a higher-variance gradient booster, and a linear predictor:

```
    g = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor()
    l = linear_model.LinearRegression()
```

Here is the methodology suggested in the answer:

```
    g.fit(x0[: 80, :], y[: 80])
    l.fit(x1[: 80, :], y[: 80])

    x[:, 0] = g.predict(x0)
    x[:, 1] = l.predict(x1)

    >>> metrics.r2_score(
        y[80: ],
        linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(x[: 80, :], y[: 80]).predict(x[80: , :]))
    0.940017788444
```

Now, using stacking:

```
    x[: 80, 0] = Stacker(g).fit_transform(x0[: 80, :], y[: 80])[:, 0]
    x[: 80, 1] = Stacker(l).fit_transform(x1[: 80, :], y[: 80])[:, 0]

    u = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(x[: 80, :], y[: 80])

    x[80: , 0] = Stacker(g).fit(x0[: 80, :], y[: 80]).transform(x0[80:, :])
    x[80: , 1] = Stacker(l).fit(x1[: 80, :], y[: 80]).transform(x1[80:, :])

    >>> metrics.r2_score(
        y[80: ],
        u.predict(x[80:, :]))
    0.992196564279
```

The stacking prediction does better. It realizes that the gradient booster is not that great.

Comment: Ami, it really rocks. But am I right that stacker has to fit each predictor I use same number of times as I have records in my training data? So instead of fitting underlying predictor once on data of 80 rows I have to actually fit it 80 times?

Comment: Thanks, @MaximHaytovich That is the reason it takes an optional cv function. If it is too expensive to build 80 predictors (which corresponds to leave-one-out), then you could perhaps build 8 (which corresponds to kfold). Doing stacking correctly is inherently more expensive, unfortunately, it seems.

Comment: in your stacking example, and given that the question was how to optimally weight the base learners rather than averaging their predictions, where can you extract the weights that the stacker assigns to the two base learners (e.g. 80% gradient boosting and 20% linear regression)?

Answer (score 10):

Ok, after spending some time on googling 'stacking' (as mentioned by @andreas earlier) I found out how I could do the weighting in python even with scikit-learn. Consider the below:

I train a set of my regression models (as mentioned SVR, LassoLars and GradientBoostingRegressor). Then I run all of them on training data (same data which was used for training of each of these 3 regressors). I get predictions for examples with each of my algorithms and save these 3 results into pandas dataframe with columns 'predictedSVR', 'predictedLASSO' and 'predictedGBR'. And I add the final column into this datafrane which I call 'predicted' which is a real prediction value.

Then I just train a linear regression on this new dataframe:

```
#df - dataframe with results of 3 regressors and true output
from sklearn linear_model
stacker= linear_model.LinearRegression()
stacker.fit(df[['predictedSVR', 'predictedLASSO', 'predictedGBR']], df['predicted'])
```

So when I want to make a prediction for new example I just run each of my 3 regressors separately and then I do:

```
stacker.predict()
```

on outputs of my 3 regressors. And get a result.

The problem here is that I am finding optimal weights for regressors 'on average, the weights will be same for each example on which I will try to make prediction.

Answer (score 5):

What you describe is called "stacking" which is not implemented in scikit-learn yet, but I think contributions would be welcome. An ensemble that just averages will be in pretty soon: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4161

Comment: Thanks. After googling for a while about stacking I found out how to do 'stacking' not with just a majority vote rule (or averaging) but with some more advanced approach. Will post it in answer shortly.

Comment: There is a nice description in elements of statistical learning.

Comment: @AndreasMueller Please see my answer below. Regarding your comment about contributions being welcome, I'd be very happy to try to contribute this, if there's interest.

Comment: Not sure I follow your code, but I don't think that's stacking. When calling ``fit``, you only fit a single base classifier, right? That looks more like what the ``VotingClassifier`` in sklearn implements.

Comment: What is the final verdict? Is that Stacker or not? and what about this one - http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/regressor/StackingRegressor/ ?

Comment: If you build a model for weighting them I'd call it stacking (in particular if you use hold-out probability estimates) and you could use the StackingRegressor. If you average I wouldn't call it stacking.

Answer (score 5):

Late response, but I wanted to add one practical point for this sort of stacked regression approach (which I use this frequently in my work).

You may want to choose an algorithm for the stacker which allows positive=True (for example, ElasticNet).  I have found that, when you have one relatively stronger model, the unconstrained LinearRegression() model will often fit a larger positive coefficient to the stronger and a negative coefficient to the weaker model.

Unless you actually believe that your weaker model has negative predictive power, this is not a helpful outcome.  Very similar to having high multi-colinearity between features of a regular regression model.  Causes all sorts of edge effects.

This comment applies most significantly to noisy data situations.  If you're aiming to get RSQ of 0.9-0.95-0.99, you'd probably want to throw out the model which was getting a negative weighting.