# How to combine two logistic regression models using python and scikit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm a Python and a Scikit newbie.
I have two Logistic Regression models created with Scikit and I want to combine them to obtain a new model.
In my mind is something like that:

```
clf1 = LogisticRegression()
clf1.fit(X_set, Y_set)
clf2 = LogisticRegression()
clf2.fit(X_set, Y_set)
combined_clf = clf1 + clf2
```

But I don't know how to do that.
Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two methods might suit your needs here.

The first one is to make each of your classifiers vote for the predicted class. To do so, you can use *sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier*. With your example:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
clf1 = LogisticRegression()
clf2 = LogisticRegression()
eclf1 = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('lr1', clf1), ('lr2', clf2),voting='hard')
eclf1 = eclf1.fit(X, Y)
```

The other one is **stacking**.
Basically, the idea is to combine the output of multiple classifiers, and train a metaclassifier on the output of your first classifiers.

Here is a useful link describing the method  : https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/classifier/StackingClassifier/.

Using mlxtend and your example:

```
from mlxtend.classifier import StackingClassifier
clf1 = LogisticRegression()
clf2 = LogisticRegression()
lr = Your_Meta_Classifier()
sclf = StackingClassifier(classifiers=[clf1, clf2], 
                      meta_classifier=lr)
```

However, in your example, the models being trained with the same deterministic methods, I don't think stacking them would lead to any improvement.

Hope it helped !

(Oh, possible duplicate of : [Ensemble of different kinds of regressors using scikit-learn (or any other python framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727709/ensemble-of-different-kinds-of-regressors-using-scikit-learn-or-any-other-pytho) ?)